# Is it possible to change counter signal to analog signal in Siemens Logo?

Tags: plc, siemens

Is it possible to change counter signal to analog signal in Siemens Logo?
When **Cnt** is for example 4, then the Analog Threshold Block is going to giving out a high signal, else low signal.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the 0BA8 version? If not, then which?

Comment: @Transistor I don't know. I can use what version of Soft Comfort I want. I'm using Soft Comfort 8.3

Comment: Yes, but various features and functions are added to each generation of the **hardware**. There's a "determine hardware" on the menu somewhere which will calculate the minimum level of hardware you require.

Comment: @Transistor I will try that in a moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this using the Mathematical instruction.

```
    +------+
    | +=   |
En -| A->  |-AQ
Par-|      |
    +------+ 

Par
V1 = B001.Cnt <--- Tie this to your B001 Cnt output.
V2 = 0
V3 = 0
V4 = 0
Op1 = +
Op2 = +
Op3 = +

Result: AQ = V1 + 0 + 0 + 0
```

You can then tie AQ as a regular analog signal to your Analog Threshold block.

Comment: Ah! I need to use the "math block" before?

Comment: @MrYui, please accept this answer if it solved your problem. That way the system won't keep popping it up as unsolved.

Comment: sorry. I did know know that would happen.

Comment: No problem. I see you've been rather good at accepting answers to your questions (but don't feel you have to if you haven't got a good enough answer).